# On swipe, buttons do not show in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Working within Ionic framework. I have a very simple app setup and cannot get the buttons to show on swipe:

```
//Swipable buttons don't work.
$scope.itemButtons = [
 {
     text: 'Edit',
     type: 'Button',
     onTap: function (item) {
         alert('Edit Item');
     }
 },
 {
     text: 'Share',
     type: 'Button',
     onTap: function (item) {
         alert('Share Item');
     }
 }
];

<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="facility in facilities" item="item" can-swipe="true" option-buttons="itemButtons">
            {{facility.name}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work by adding <ion-list can-swipe="true" option-buttons="itemButtons">

Answer (score 5):

You also have a small bug - you should set `item="facility"`, not `item="item"`.  But more importantly, this syntax is not available in [nightly-1.0.0-beta.1](http://code.ionicframework.com/#nightly).  The new syntax looks like this:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="facility in facilities" item="facility" can-swipe="true">
      Facility {{ facility .id }}
      <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="edit(facility)">
        Edit
      </ion-option-button>
      <ion-option-button class="button-calm" ng-click="share(facility)">
        Share
      </ion-option-button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

js:

```
$scope.edit = function(item) {
  alert('Edit facility: ' + item.id);
};
$scope.share = function(item) {
  alert('Share facility: ' + item.id);
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/isubGyXN3FEy5hNIuUlR?p=preview

Comment: I guess this relies on the nightly build, and couldn't find the docs for this. In 1.0.0-beta1, I was able to get this to work by adding <ion-list can-swipe="true" option-buttons="itemButtons">.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: i edited my answer to identify the correct build in which syntax is changing. but, the answer isn't applicable to you given that you are not using the nightly.  you should post the solution you found for 1.0.0-beta.1 (moving `option-buttons` to `ion-list`), since the example in the docs doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Adding    `can-swipe="true" option-buttons="itemButtons"` to the parent element seemed to fix this for me in 1.0.0-beta.1

```
<ion-list can-swipe="true" option-buttons="itemButtons">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="facility in facilities" item="facility" ng-click="setFacilityId(facility.id)" href="#/app/facility">
            {{facility}}
        </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```